# django Expiration object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using an activation system to verify the user email and now in the active_code model , I wnat only the objects that are created 120 seconds ago . But it even accepts the objects that are created more than 120 seconds ago . Help me please!

```
def Activation_page(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = forms.Active(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        past_seconds = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(seconds=120)
        if active_code.objects.filter(email = request.session['email'] , code = data['num'] , expiration__gte=past_seconds).exists() :
            try:
                b = User.objects.get(email = request.session['email'])
                b.is_active = True
                b.save()
                return redirect('home:loginveiw')
            except:
                messages.error(request , 'error')
        else:
            messages.error(request , 'error_2')
else:
    form = forms.Active()
return render(request , 'home/activation.html' , {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem more? I don't understand what went wrong.

Comment: well It does not work right , It accepts even the code objects that they are created one hour ago!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the use of `date()` function that is wrong. You should remove that  and use only `timezone.now() - timedelta(seconds=120)`. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-timedelta-function/.

When using the `date()` function you set the time of today but at 00:00 so of course the codes from an hour ago get accepted.